# Detect job category from job title and description

Tags: elasticsearch, machine-learning, text, text-classification

I have a table in database with job positions (title and job description) [50 000 records] and separate table with job categories (flat hierarchy) [1 000 records].
Goal is to pair each job with 1 to 3 categories.
What is the best way how to do it? My database is MySQL, everything is also in ElasticSearch. I can use also some cloud solution.
Is there some already created solution, where I can send 2 data sets and get pairing between them?

Comment: Do you have any labelled data, i.e. examples of pairs (title+description, category)? If not it's going to be challenging since you can't train a model.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. That's the reason I don't want to train my own models. And I was thinking if there is any solution, which is working not as machine learning, but something more simple, like texts similarities etc.

Comment: If you don't have any labelled data one of the problems is that you can't evaluate whatever solution you try. You could try similarity measures indeed, but you will need to determine a threshold for selecting a category. You would probably have the usual problem that some categories get selected very often just because some frequent words match their words, and conversely. If you want a more advanced solution you could use some similarity between word embeddings.